# Where do applications run when launched from within an application being delivered over Citrix Presentation Server

Tags: registry, citrix

I am working with a fairly old proprietary application that (amongst other things) launches Excel for exporting data. As a stand-alone application, this works fine, and Excel is launched from the machine running the application.

However, the application is now going to be delivered via CITRIX Presentation Server 4.5, that is, the application is displayed remotely as opposed to connecting to a remote desktop.

I don't have access to the source code, so am unsure as to how it is actually launching the instance of Excel

My question is when the application launches Excel, is Excel run on the CITRIX server and presented, or does it run locally on the clients' machine? Is there any way to configure the CITRIX environment to force it to run either on the server or on the client?

Additionally, the application uses Registry settings. Will these registry settings read/write somewhere in the CITRIX environment, or on the local client machine?

I am finding the lines between client and server a bit blurry when it comes to presenting an application (as opposed to desktop) remotely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Citrix Presentation Server (nowadays called XenApp) is easier to understand if you think of it as a multiuser version of Windows. Imagine a big fat machine with lots of monitors and keyboards attached to it. That is how it works, except that the monitors and keyboards are attached virtually over the network.

As to your questions: if a process runs on the Citrix server and launches another process, that happens on the Citrix server. Applications typically do not behave differently on terminal servers than on regular PCs.

And no, there is no way to configure the Citrix server to force Excel (in your case) to run on either the server or the client. Excel will always run on the server. That is true if a Citrix feature called "content redirection" is not used, which is probably not the case.

Registry settings are always read/written where the process in question runs, in your case on the Citrix server.